# How do you say 'around', as in "Walk around Lake Burley Griffin"

Tags: phrase-requests

I have looked into it, but I can't find the answer.
When I say 'around', I mean walking along the perimeter of the lake and returning to the same place we started at.
Google Translate says that it is Burley Griffin湖を歩きます.
My guess is:

> 「バーリーグリフィン湖一周に歩きます。」

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let's talk about noun phrases that might be used to express the concept of a walk around something.

> xx一周ウォーク
>
> xx一周ウォーキング
>
> 徒歩でxx一周する
>
> xxを歩いて一周する

The first two are most commonly used in terms of a predesigned course or trail that you might take around something. All these terms can be used with standard verbs such as する or 始める. However, there is a special verb that can be used to indicate completion of a walk 完歩{かんぽ}, specifically for the first two examples. It doesn't seem to be used in the case of the latter two presumably because you already said 歩. In fact, you can just say

> xx一周完歩しました

to say you finished walking around something.

Here are some other ways you can say it, especially for a larger thing such as Lake Biwa or Japan (or I suppose if you want to make it seem like a long trip), you might say

> xx一周(する)歩き(旅)
>
> xx一周徒歩 (旅 or 旅行)

For going around the world (obviously you can't do it all by walking), it seems the more common way to say you completed it would be :

> 世界一周徒歩旅を達成した

Comment: Downvoters, could you please comment on what you think is wrong or missing from this post?

Comment: I didn't vote, but I do think this answer is missing a way of expressing the idea without using 漢語 or 外来語. Not that there's anything wrong with these phrasings, but I feel like the use of 漢語 especially makes them sound a bit stiff. In everyday conversation I would prefer something like 「湖の周りを（歩いて）一回りする」 or 「湖の周りを（歩いて）一回まわる」 and of course if the walking part is already understood then we can omit 歩いて.

Comment: ^ 日常会話で、「湖を歩いて一周する」「湖の周りを歩いて一周する」って、いいと思いますけど・・　（「湖一周ウォーク」「完歩しました」「湖一周する歩き」「一周徒歩旅」とかは言わないけど）